# C Returning string array

Tags: c, arrays

I want this program to return an array, and then a variable from main to get this array from the function, and be usable in a part of code that has to verify a string against these values from the initial variable.
But the variable doesn't get the returned array.
I've seen some posts saying that you cannot return arrays in C, but I've also seen other post where this was possible.

But I want to know what can I do to catch this returned value.

```
int getUsers()
{
    char userVect[5][25];
    char user[24];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k;

    FILE  *usernames;
    usernames = fopen("usernames.cfg", "r");
    if (usernames == NULL){
        perror("usernames - err");
        return(-1);
    }

    while(fgets(user, sizeof(user), usernames) !=NULL){
        strcpy(userVect[j], user);
        j++;
    }

    fclose(usernames);
    for(k=0; k<j; k++)
        printf("Usernames are:  %s\n", userVect[k]);

    return userVect;
}

int main()
{
    printf("\nWelcome to Sys v1.24. To start off, please insert your command. \n");
    char *users;
    users = getUsers();
    printf("%c\n", users);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are returning stack variable (userVect) from getUsers() function. As soon as, the getUsers() function call is returned, 'userVect' stack storage variable is not valid to be used. Either you can declare userVect in main() and pass it to getUsers(), yes, getUsers() will be able to update its content Or you can dynamically allocated pointer in getUsers() and return it.

Comment: Then main reason why this is not working is that function getUser() is returning int. This will give output correctly on a 32 bit system where sizeof(int)==sizeof(ptr). But on 64 bit systems size of int and size of ptr are different, hence the issue. Also userVect[5][25], need to be made global or declared inside main and passed to function getUsers();

Answer (score -6, accepted):

#### The function getUser() should return a char*

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    char userVect[5][25];
    char* getUsers(){ 
        char user[24];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k;

        FILE  *usernames;
        usernames = fopen("usernames.cfg", "r");
        if (usernames == NULL){
            perror("usernames - err");
            return(-1);
        }

        while(fgets(user, sizeof(user), usernames) !=NULL){
            strcpy(userVect[j], user);
            j++;
        }

        fclose(usernames);
        for(k=0; k<j; k++)
            printf("Usernames are:  %s\n", userVect[k]);

        return userVect;
    }

    int main(){
        printf("\nWelcome to Sys v1.24. To start off, please insert your command. \n");
        char *users;
        users = getUsers();
        printf("%c\n", users);

        return 0;
    }
```

you can also declare userVect[5][25] in main() and pass it as an argument to getUsers() function.

You can also get the data in heap (via malloc), but for small dataset like this I wouldn't recommend.

Then main reason why this is not working is that function getUser() was returning int. This will give output correctly on a 32 bit system where sizeof(int)==sizeof(ptr). But on 64 bit systems size of int and size of ptr are different.

You also need to consider point 3 from @ameyCU answer regarding printing the output.

Comment: If this works it is pure luck. Returning a pointer to the stack is extremely bad practice in C.

Comment: userVect is stack variable and being returned from function getUsers(). This is wrong.

Comment: There are lots of other issues with this code as well which the author will need to take a look at. Making the array global will work. There are also 5 compiler warning that will need to be looked into. I just pointed the main issue with the code.

Answer (score 7):

**1.** You want to `return` a string and your function has type `int`??

I see you return a `2-d` array, then your function should be of type `char **` -

```
char **getUser(void)
```

**2.** You return local variable (`userVect`) from your function. You cannot access it outside function block .

You should  do this in you function `getUser`-

```
char **userVect;
userVect=malloc(5*sizeof(char **));              //allocate memory  
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   userVect[i]=malloc(25*sizeof(char));
```

And in `main` do this -

```
char **user;
...
user=getUsers();                 // call function
```

**3.** And to print`user` in `main` -

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%s\n", user[i]);          //this is wrong in your code- printf("%c\n", users);
```

And then `free` it in `main` at then end-

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    free(user[i]);
free(user);
```

Comment: For a small dataset like this one a stack should be sufficient, I would go the heap route.

Comment: @sdayal I don't see a problem in using dynamic allocation  . But if you want pass array to function from `main` , if you don't want to use dynamic allocation .

Comment: Dynamic allocation poses more risk in maintaining. For small data sets why would you want to change his code to heap?

Comment: @sdayal That's opinion based and there wont  be risk if you are aware what you are doing . And small dataset is no reason for not using dynamic allocation IMHO . But as I said its on your opinion :-)

Comment: That's not the point. You are suggesting a code change that is not necessary in this case (it's just fancy). Global Stack pointer can happily passed around as along as they are within small size limit.

Comment: @sdayal So , you are suggestion to use global variable ??

Comment: This is going to be my last comment on this thread. Then main reason why the author of this question was not able to get his code working was because the function getUser() was returning int. He would have got the output correctly on a 32 bit system where sizeof(int)==sizeof(ptr). But on 64 bit systems size of int and size of ptr are different. Only making the function return a pointer and making the array global (or placed inside main) was what needed.

Comment: @sdayal I wouldn't have used global array rather avoiding is better , for such things its completely unnecessary . If you dont want to use dynamic allocation then pass array to function from `main`  that's better than using global vairables.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a stack variable. It won't be valid in `main()`. You should either allocate it on the heap (using `malloc`) or make it a global variable (in which case there is no need to return it at all).

Answer (score 0):

```
char ** getUsers(){
    char **userVect;
char user[24];
int i = 0, j = 0, k;

userVect=malloc(5*sizeof(char **));              //allocate memory  

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    userVect[i]=malloc(25*sizeof(char)); 

FILE  *usernames;
usernames = fopen("usernames.cfg", "r");
if (usernames == NULL){
    perror("usernames - err");
    return(-1);
}

    while(fgets(user, sizeof(user), usernames) !=NULL){
    strcpy(userVect[j], user);
    j++;
}

fclose(usernames);
for(k=0; k<j; k++)
    printf("Usernames are:  %s\n", userVect[k]);

return userVect;`
```

`int main(){
printf("\nWelcome to Sys v1.24. To start off, please insert your command. \n");
char **users;

users = getUsers();

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%s\n", user[i]);

return 0;
}`